# How to re-allocate amounts from existing lines

Tags: sql, database

trying to create a database with sales order records and re-allocate the total transaction price among the sales order line items with different values based on certain rules.

For example, if I have a $100 sales order with two lines that is composed of software and maintenance, let's say the software is contracted at $100 and maintenance is free. If I were to allocate $50 from software to maintenance so they'll both have $50 allocated value for each line, what is the best way to do this?

I'm thinking about adding another column/field where we retain the original amounts per the sales order but trying to see how I can apply a certain rule (such as higher of comparison) and allocate the total sales order value into different amounts than what is contracted.

Note that I'm trying to calculate the allocated amount as that will be null initially when I create the sales order data.

Thanks all

[image: sample]

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Just updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your database and it depends on your "certain rules" but to get you started the following will work in SQL Server and possibly others.

To evenly split all revenue for a sales order (so) across all lines (line) in that sales order equally:

```
update tbl
set Alloc = new_alloc
from
(select 
   so, 
   line, 
   (sum(contracted) over (partition by so))/
     (count(line) over (partition by so)) as new_alloc
 from tbl) as sub
 where sub.so = tbl.so
   and sub.line = tbl.lineenter code here
```

To apply custom rules based on Line Description (in this case 80% to 'Software' 20% to 'Maintenance'):

```
update tbl
set Alloc = new_alloc
from
(select 
   so, 
   line, 
   case when line_description = 'Software' then 0.8 
        when line_description = 'Maintenance' then 0.2 
        end *
     sum(contracted) over (partition by so) as new_alloc
 from tbl) as sub
 where sub.so = tbl.so
   and sub.line = tbl.line
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/517816/4)

Comment: i think you get where i'm coming from :) will take a look at this. thank you